# Convert string of unknown encoding to UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am consuming a text response from a third party API. This text is in an encoding which is unknown to me. I consume the text in python3 and want to change the encoding into UTF-8.

This is an example of the contents I get:

```
Danke
"TrÃ¤ume groÃŸ"
ðŸ™ŒðŸ¼
Super Idee!!!
```

I was able to get the messed up characters readable by doing the following manually:

1. Open new document in Notepad++
2. Via the *Encoding* menu switch the encoding of the document to `ANSI`
3. Paste the contents
4. Again use the *Encoding* menu, this time switch to `UTF-8`
5. Now the text is properly legible like below

Correct content:

```
Danke
"Träume groß"

Super Idee!!!
```

I want to repeat this process in python3, but struggle to do so. From the notepad workflow I gather that the encoding shouldn't be converted, rather the existing characters should be interpreted with a different encoding. That's because if I select *Convert to UTF-8* in the *Encoding* menu, it doesn't work.

From what I have read on SO, there are the `encode` and `decode` methods to do that. Also `ANSI` isn't really an encoding but rather refers to the standard encoding the current machine uses. This would most likely be `cp1525` on my windows machine. I have messed around with all combinations of `cp1252` and `utf-8` as source and/or target, but to no avail. I always end up with a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

I have also tried using the `chardet` module to determine the encoding of my input string, but it requires `bytes` as input and `b'ðŸ™ŒðŸ¼'` is rejected with `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`

Comment: You *cannot* reliably convert something which you don't know what it is. If you *know* what encoding it's in (or have a good guess), you can explicitly convert the encoding in certain steps to perhaps fix the mojibake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"TrÃ¤ume groÃŸ"` is a hint that you got something originally encoded as utf-8, but your process read it as cp1252.

A possible way is to encode your string back to cp1252 and then correctly decode it as utf-8:

```
print('"TrÃ¤ume groÃŸ"'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))
```

gives as expected:

```
"Träume groß"
```

But this is only a workaround. The correct solution is to understand where you have read the original bytes as cp1252 and directly use the utf8 conversion there.

Comment: I tried this exact process of using `encode` and `decode`. While you're right that it works for `'"TrÃ¤ume groÃŸ"'`, it doesn't work for the emoji and throws a `UnicodeEncodeError`

Regarding your suggestion of tackling the root: I am using `requests` to get the text. I did some web searching to find out how to change the encoding it uses. That lead me to check `response.encoding`, which returned `ISO-8859-1` in this case. So now that I know what the source encoding is, `response.text.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('utf8')` or shorter `response.content.decode('utf8')` gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bytes()` to convert a string to bytes, and then decode it with `.decode()`

```
>>> bytes("TrÃ¤ume groÃŸ", "cp1252").decode("utf-8")
'Träume groß'
```

Comment: Note that this approach depends on the encoding of your text editor/terminal/copy-paste-system… Copy-pasting mojibake is very brittle.

Comment: Ha, I didn't think of a the simple option of using a typecast.

Answer (score 0):

[chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) could probably be useful here -

Quoting straight from the [docs](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage)

```
import urllib.request
rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
import chardet
chardet.detect(rawdata) {'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried it but unfortunately it returned an unusable result in my case. 

Since I am using the `requests` module, I was able to find the proper encoding by checking the value of `response.encoding`